# Java is not letting me use records

Tags: java

I'm running JDK 15 (Just downloaded it) and I'm getting a compile error when I try to use records:

```
public class Runner {

    // This gives a compile error
    record Point(int x, int y) {}

}
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>something</groupId>
    <artifactId>other-thing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Records are still a preview feature in Java 15, so you will need to add the `--enable-preview` argument when running the compiler:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Huh. I could've sworn I saw that they were finalized. Ok then. That makes sense lol. Thanks.